# Using MATLAB I am trying to plot the van der pol equation for man epsilons?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot solutions to the van der Pol equations for many epsilons my code is:

```
tspan = [0, 10];
y0 = [0.5; 0];  % Initial location

for ep = 0.1:0.2:2.5  % Loop through a few epsilons
    ode = @(t,y) vanderpol(t,y,ep);   % Call vanderpol.m for the points (t,y)
    [t,y] = ode45(ode, tspan, y0);    % solve Van der Pol equation

    % Plot of the solution

    plot(t,y(:,1)); drawnow;
    %xlabel('Time');
    %ylabel('Van der Pol Solution');
    %title('Solutions to van der Pol equation for many \epsilon');
end
```

I want plots of the van der Pol equation for each epsilon on each plot. Not really sure how to do this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use `figure` to create different plots:

```
tspan = [0, 10];
y0 = [0.5; 0];  % Initial location

for ep = 0.1:0.2:2.5  % Loop through a few epsilons
    ode = @(t,y) vanderpol(t,y,ep);   % Call vanderpol.m for the points (t,y)
    [t,y] = ode45(ode, tspan, y0);    % solve Van der Pol equation

    % Plot of the solution

    figure,  

    plot(t,y(:,1)); drawnow;
    %xlabel('Time');
    %ylabel('Van der Pol Solution');
    %title('Solutions to van der Pol equation for many \epsilon');
end
```

for a single plot use `hold on`

```
tspan = [0, 10];
y0 = [0.5; 0];  % Initial location

for ep = 0.1:0.2:2.5  % Loop through a few epsilons
    ode = @(t,y) vanderpol(t,y,ep);   % Call vanderpol.m for the points (t,y)
    [t,y] = ode45(ode, tspan, y0);    % solve Van der Pol equation

    % Plot of the solution

    plot(t,y(:,1)); drawnow;
    %xlabel('Time');
    %ylabel('Van der Pol Solution');
    %title('Solutions to van der Pol equation for many \epsilon');
    hold on
end
```

Comment: Thank You for the response, this makes many plots but I want them all to appear on a single plot is there a way to do that?

Comment: @user2144933 just write hold on before the loop, hold off after the loot and remoove the "figure" line.